# In which results, identities, or formulae does $\pi$ appear not in a totally geometric setting?

Tags: pi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the number pi have any significance besides being the ratio of a circle's diameter to its circumference?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/does-the-number-pi-have-any-significance-besides-being-the-ratio-of-a-circles-d)

For an education assignment, I would like a selection of various results, identities, or fomulae in which $\pi = 3.14159...$ appears. In particular, results which are not immediately obvious as being totally geometric, as the definition of $\pi$ is, for example. So far I have recalled Euler's $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6},$$ and identities involving the Gamma function, Stirling's formula and its use in probability. I wish to create an excercise whereby students may evaluate the pros and cons of universally replacing $\pi $ with $\frac{\tau }{2}$ throughout mathematical literature and textbooks, but also learn mathematics. [Question 26918](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26918/why-is-pi-3-14-instead-of-6-28) is similar.

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36759/interesting-facts-about-pi, although not much happened there.

Comment: Ah yes, no worries about closing the question. I can probably do that myself!

Comment: Yes, Question 3320 answers enough. I don't know how to close my question other than to vote for closing it.